# Homotopy equivalence between the topological spaces which are homeomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and suppose that $f: X \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence. Is $f$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: No... For any contactable space constant map is homotopy equivalence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $f:(0,1)\to (0,1)$ given by $f(x)=x/2$, and $g$ is the identity. Then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both homotopic to the identity, but $f$ is not surjective, so it is not a homeomorphism.